# Endpoint suspension and SLL engine error while connecting to sfdc from wso2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 esb 4.8.1.I uploaded sfdc connector for both esb and developer studio. I created local entry to store sfdc credentials and using config key in my code to connect to sfdc. But am getting the fallowing error while trying to connect sfdc. In the test environment the same credentials are working fine.

```
  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/connect_to_sfdc.connect_to_sfdcHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:8ce508a1-f454-49c2-a232-f3d824a13f1d, Direction: request, property_name = Connecting to sfdc, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2015-12-18 22:30:50,438]  INFO - LogMediator Connection = Login to Salesforce .....
[2015-12-18 22:30:51,241] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1348)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:519)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1197)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1169)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doWrap(SSLIOSession.java:220)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:118)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:342)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:320)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:604)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1703)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:281)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1446)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:853)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:851)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1285)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doRunTask(SSLIOSession.java:238)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:270)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:283)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:138)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1433)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 23 more
[2015-12-18 22:30:51,248]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2015-12-18 22:30:51,249]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint - last suspend duration was : 2000ms and current suspend duration is : 2000ms - Next retry after : Fri Dec 18 22:30:53 IST 2015
[2015-12-18 22:31:20,551]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2015-12-18 22:31:20,551+0530]
[2015-12-18 22:31:50,475]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-4
[2015-12-18 22:31:50,479]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/connect_to_sfdc.connect_to_sfdcHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:0dccdbfb-7d47-42a6-b6bb-2e10a9ac16b2, Direction: request, property_name = Connecting to sfdc, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2015-12-18 22:31:50,483]  INFO - LogMediator Connection = Login to Salesforce .....
[2015-12-18 22:31:51,283] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1348)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:519)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1197)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1169)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doWrap(SSLIOSession.java:220)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:118)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:342)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:320)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:604)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1703)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:281)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1446)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:853)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:851)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1285)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doRunTask(SSLIOSession.java:238)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:270)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:283)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:138)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1433)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 23 more
[2015-12-18 22:31:51,298]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2015-12-18 22:31:51,298]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint - last suspend duration was : 2000ms and current suspend duration is : 2000ms - Next retry after : Fri Dec 18 22:31:53 IST 2015
[2015-12-18 22:32:50,538]  INFO - HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://rb-VirtualBox:8284/services/connect_to_sfdc.connect_to_sfdcHttpSoap12Endpoint]
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:622)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:451)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:278)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:554)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:530)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.jsp.WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.admin.jsp.WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp:276)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-12-18 22:32:50,554]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-5
^C[2015-12-18 22:50:21,359]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Shutdown hook triggered....`enter code here`
```

Comment: seems like a certificate issue , have you imported the certificate in your client-truststore? SSL Engine and PKIX error suggest that.

Comment: ya I imported the certificate. It was problem with certificate only. Fixed the issue by deleting the previous certificate and imported again to client-trust store. Now it's working fine.

Comment: good to know it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to https://login.salesforce.com/ in chrome and click the padlock sign
click connection tab and click certificate information
click details tab and click authority information access and you can find the crt link
go to CA Issuers: URI:http://se.symcb.com/se.crt. a .crt file will be downloaded. copy and paste it in the /repository/resources/security folder.
then in the terminal, go to the above folder and type the following command.

keytool -importcert -file se.crt -keystore client-truststore.jks -alias “sf”      if they ask for password give it as “wso2carbon”
 then restart the ESB.
Then it will works fine.**Remember that You must login in to salesforce which you are trying to access. Then fallow above procedure.**